# Getting bitmap null while converting url to bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I want to download the image from server and convert it to bitmap. I tried to download the image and convert it to bitmap but it returns null. I get bitmap as null.

To convert image to bitmap I have created one asyncTask.

Passing url to Async task :

```
String url = ServiceUrl.getBaseUrl() + ServiceUrl.getImageUserUrl() + profileImage;
            Log.e("url", url);


   new ImageUserTask(mContext, url, profileImage).execute();
```

ImageUserAsync Task:

```
   public class ImageUserTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {
    String imageprofile;
    private String url;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageUserTask(Context context, String url, String imageprofile) {
        this.url = url;
       this.imageprofile = imageprofile;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            //Url
            URL urlConnection = new URL(url);
            //Conntecting httpUrlConnection
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            //Connected to server
            connection.connect();
            //downloading  image
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            //converting image to bitmap
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

            return myBitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null; 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (result != null) {


            result = mBitmap;

            new ImageServer(mContext).save(result);

        }
    }

}
```

EDIT :

Tried to use picasso :

```
        @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);
        count=0;
        if (response.has("message")) {
            JSONObject userJson = null;
            String message = null;
            count++;
            try {

                if (response.getString("message").equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_SUCCESS)) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "user authenticated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    userJson = response.getJSONObject("user");
                    String userId = userJson.getString("user_id");
                    String userName = userJson.getString("user_name");
                    String profileImage = userJson.getString("profile_image");
                    String mobileNo = userJson.getString("mobile_no");


                    String url = ServiceUrl.getBaseUrl() + ServiceUrl.getImageUserUrl() + profileImage;
                    Log.e("url", url);

                    User user = new User();

                    user.setmUserId(userId);
                    user.setmUserName(userName);

                    user.setmProfileImage(profileImage);
                    user.setmMobileNo(mobileNo);

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences("username",mContext.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putString("UserUsername",userName);
                    editor.commit();

                    Target target = new Target() {
                        @Override
                        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

                            try {

                                File f = new File(mContext.getCacheDir(), "Profile");
                                f.createNewFile();

//Convert bitmap to byte array
                                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
                                byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

//write the bytes in file
                                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                                fos.write(bitmapdata);
                                fos.flush();
                                fos.close();
                                Log.e("File",String.valueOf(f));
                            }
                            catch (IOException e)
                            {

                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                        }

                        @Override
                       public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                        }
                    };

                        Picasso.with(mContext).load(url).into(target);


                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "user authenticated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    Picasso.with(mContext).cancelRequest(target);
                   }
                 }
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: post your logcat error?

Comment: have you checked the url if the image really exists there?

Comment: My first thought is to log the actual URL that is passed to ImageUserTask.

Comment: you can use picasso.

Comment: url dose exists. Also I have logged url. I get the url. Its not throwing any exception. I did debug so I got to know. @AmanGrover

Comment: url dose exists. Also I have logged url. I get the url. Its not throwing any exception. I did debug so I got to know. @mm759

Comment: Its not throwing any exception. I did debug so I got to know. @Nisarg

Comment: @Sid Make sure you have put Internet permission in manifest and check for url if its working or not

Comment: I have put internet permissions in app, also url is working. @Nisarg

Comment: I get this url in log  http://xesoftwares.co.in/contactsapi/profile_images/d34b638b93773140eb94d5f03c20237c.jpg @Nisarg

Answer (score 1):

Try this I am getting image by this method.

```
                URL url1l = new URL("<Image url>");

                URLConnection connection = url1l.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
                int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

                // download the file
                InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

Comment: Then check image is exist or not? @Sid

Comment: I get this url in log http://xesoftwares.co.in/contactsapi/profile_images/d34b638b93773140eb94d5f03c20237c.jpg @Furqan

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that you are getting an error from the server or that the data you are getting back cannot be decoded. First of all, check the response code after the connection is opened:

```
connection.connect();
int respCode = connection.getResponseCode();
Log.d("resp code", "response code " + respCode);
```

If you get anything other than 200, then something is wrong with retrieving data (wrong url, auth, or server error). If you do get 200, then the issue is with the data you are receiving. Read the data into a byte array and dump it into a file to examine.

Answer (score -1):

First check with image is really exists or not as @aman grover said 
if available use [Picasso Lib](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to download image and from url.

here is sample code

```
private Target target = new Target() {
      @Override
      public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
      //Note : here you can get Bitmap 

      }

      @Override
      public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
      }
}

private void someMethod() {
   Picasso.with(this).load("url").into(target);
}

@Override 
public void onDestroy() {  // could be in onPause or onStop
   Picasso.with(this).cancelRequest(target);
   super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: User haven't asked for any library help

Comment: @RahulKhurana but its better to use picasso then Async Task and with that he can easily get Bitmap

Comment: I tried using picasso but bitmapLoaded dose not get execute. @pcpriyanka

Comment: print log in onBitmapFailed or prepareLoad and check where is going and if possible provide URL from where you are downloading Image

Comment: provide URL from where you are downloading Image

Comment: from where? I am not getting it. Could you please explain with code? @pcpriyanka

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124008/discussion-between-sid-and-pcpriyanka).

Comment: String url = ServiceUrl.getBaseUrl() + ServiceUrl.getImageUserUrl() + profileImage;
            Log.e("url", url); what value its printing your logcat